# Поменять скобки не затронув значение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Notepad++ с помощью регулярок 
найти все скобки внутри которых год, например `(1997)`,
и заменить эти скобки на квадратные скобки, чтобы стало `[1997]`.

Comment: `\((\d+)\)` заменяешь на `[$1]`, demo: https://regex101.com/r/XhPc8M/1

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Лучше ровно 4 вхождения цифр, а то может и две затронуть и шесть.

Comment: @AK, согласен, в демо так и сделал.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает

Comment: Если вам дали исчёрпывающий ответ - примите его поставив галку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти годы от 1900 до 2099, можно использовать шаблон `(?:19|20)\d{2}`.

Используйте

```
\(((?:19|20)\d{2})\)
```

Шаблон замены:

```
[$1]
```

**Подробности**

- `\(` - символ `(`
- `((?:19|20)\d{2})` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 (значение которой можно получить в шаблоне замены с помощью `$1`):

  - `(?:19|20)` - `19` или `20`
  - `\d{2}` - 2 цифры
- `\)` - символ `)`

Демо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотите заменить круглый скобки вокруг любых 4 цифр, используйте `\((\d{4})\)`, где `\d{4}` находит 4 любых цифры.

Answer (score 1):

Если данные с новой строки, можно использовать:

```
\((.*)\)$
```

На что заменяем:

```
[\1]
```

Если данные в тексте, можно использовать:

```
\((\d+)\)
```

И заменяем

```
[\1]
```

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на свой результат: https://regex101.com/r/XhPc8M/2

Comment: Конец строки (`$`) здесь никак не должен присутствовать, например дан текст, и скобки с годами будут в разных местах, не только на конце строки. Используя `.*` 0 и более символов вы захватите все на своем пути, если же добавить ленивый квантификатор `?` и получится `.*?`, то здесь тоже никто не дает гарантии, так как у юзера может быть любой контент в скобках, а нам исключительно цифры нужны, т. е. `\d`.

Comment: в вопросе не было указаний что данные находятся в тексте

Comment: автор говорит, что ему нужно заменить ***ВСЕ скобки внутри которых год***, можно предположить, что скобка будет не одна, и не факт, что на конце строки, ну это имхо разумеется.

Comment: правильно написали что не факт, что с новой строки, поэтому я и изменил ответ